# Can I run 2 separate stacks for each group?

Tags: plumbing, drain-waste-vent

I am wanting to run 2 separate stacks. One for second floor bathroom and one for first floor bathroom. Both stacks will tie in together in the basement where the main line runs around the house then out. I figure this is the best way as far as venting is concerned. Both stacks would be 3” and go out the roof. Or I might tie them together in the attic. Is this a plausible idea?

Comment: Location of the two bathrooms in the house?  If close to each other, a second stack is just wasted money, it adds no benefit.  If far apart(at each end of the house), it will probably be a requirement to have two stacks.

Comment: right above. I just can’t find a way to drain and vent everything the right way. So far 3 plumbers have quoted me thousands of dollars which I don’t have.

Comment: What is your applicable plumbing code - i.e. IPC, UPC, either of those with local modifications, some other base code...? These things vary locally, so what passes where I am may or may not pass where you are.

Answer (score 0):

It's plausible, but depending on layout it might well not be sensible.

If the facilities are located over each other, one "stack" ("vent stack" above the top floor fixtures, "waste stack" below that point) and a dry vent serving the lower level is more common and reasonable, with the lower floor dry vent joining the upper floor stack vent where it is also a dry vent (more than 6" above the flood rim of the highest fixture on the floor. Often in the attic.)

If things are not all vertically aligned, then a separate stack for each vertical grouping of waste facilities in scattered parts of the house, rather than per floor makes more sense - again, with a dry vent for the floors other than the top one - required if there's a toilet above, (the stack below a toilet discharge is not considered a vent in code) makes the vent capacity considerably greater .vs. a wet vent if the things above are not toilets. Consult the venting tables in your applicable code.

In most cases, the dry vent (air only) can be considerably smaller than the waste stack (sewage).

*If you have the space for it and want to "best way" your drains and vents, head up a size (4" stack and use 2" dry vents, other than the top of the stack out the roof at 4")* That may or may not work for you depending on your plumbing space in the walls. It does cost more and is not likely to be required to meet code. Also not an option if you have an existing 3" main line out of the house.